# Composer - How to add own packages to list

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

When using composer how are the packages resolved and how can a custom package be added?

An example would be that I have a custom application and I want people to be able to use composer to get my package. How would I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Packagist](http://packagist.org/) is the main Composer repository. You can submit your package to [Packagist.](http://packagist.org/) and then you can ask others who want to use your package, to just add your package to their `composer.json` file .

You can find more information on how to create a package on [About Packagist Page.](http://packagist.org/about)

Comment: While this is true and all, Packagist isn't made to store random garbage, so in case you just need stuff internally or for tests, please use the repositories feature of composer: see docs at http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md

Answer (score 5):

For further reference:

As explained in the [Composer Documentation > VCS Repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs), add in your project the repository referencing your fork, and it will use your repository instead the one of packagist:

```
{
    "name": "acme/my-app",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/yourusername/project-name"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "repo/project-name": "dev-master"
    }
}
```